# Grey dots/squares in my Ionic App since Webview Update

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview

Getting these annoying small grey squares with my Ionic App since I updated the WebView Service on my Android device. They sometimes disappear when I interact with the App and only occur on my android devices, not on my laptop when launched with "ionic serve". I didn't know what to search for, is this a bug or anything you can fix?

Edit: The dots appear to be in the top-left of the divs.

In the screenshot it's on the right side:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your code and what you've tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani is the HTML enough? should I upload the CSS too?

Comment: I am no HTML/CSS expert so I can't help you solve this problem. But for others to be able to find the problem, you can read "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out that these are just scrollbars that were made visible with the new WebView update.
Just had to add this to my code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue after put below css in  app.scss file and it worked for me.

```
/* Used for remove the gray dot square in whole pp*/
::-webkit-scrollbar, *::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```